# How can I tell what installed version of QML modules I have?

Tags: qt, qml

```
import QtQuick3D 1.15
```

gives:

> qrc:/main.qml:4:1: module "QtQuick3D" version 1.15 is not installed

I have tried looking into `<Qt-prefix>/share/qt/qml/QtQuick3D`, but `qmldir` only contains:

```
module QtQuick3D
linktarget Qt6::qquick3dplugin
plugin qquick3dplugin
classname QQuick3DPlugin
designersupported
typeinfo plugins.qmltypes
depends QtQuick auto
prefer :/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick3D/
```

`plugins.qmltypes` contains more stuff, e.g.:

```
Module {
    Component {
        file: "private/qquick3dabstractlight_p.h"
        name: "QQuick3DAbstractLight"
        exports: ["QtQuick3D/Light 6.0"]
        ...
```

but I'm not sure what I should be looking at. Is it the version number mentioned in `Module > Component . exports` the one I am looking for?

Comment: Starting from Qt6, you can drop the numbers from the imports.

Comment: It's not so easy, but when you're using Qt Creator the editor is helping you by autocomplete the module's number.